# purrr equivalent of grep + argument

Tags: r, purrr

I am scraping data and I wonder how can I write a `purrr` line equivalent to `grep` to keep all strings that are links to rar or xlsx files.

This works:

```
x <- read_html("http://datos.gob.cl/dataset/registros-de-exportacion-2009") %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  grep(paste(c("\\.rar", "\\.xlsx"), collapse = "|"), ., value = T)
```

How ever, is there a way to write `grep(...)` as `keep(...)` for a more simple writing?

Comment: How would it be any different than this? How would this new function look different that what you currently have. Do you want to change the output of the function or the input parameters? `grep` and `keep` are the same number of letters so i'm not sure what part you are trying to make "more simple."

Comment: I was thinking about something like `keep(~x %in% c(...)` but that's not the way to go

Comment: You could use `keep(~grepl(pattern, .x))` (using `grepl` rather than `grep`) if you think that looks more simple. For example `letters[1:10] %>% keep(~grepl("b|c", .x))`